# Could not find a base address that matches scheme https. wcf on visual studio localhost

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-config

I am trying to use wcf on both https and http.

I manage to config the web.config to work on the server both http and https.

the problem is that wcf not working on the visual studio localhost(doesn't have ssl).

the web.config look like this

```
 <webHttpBinding>

        <binding name="webBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="webBindingNotSecure">
          <security mode="None">
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
```

and then 2 endpoint for http and https:

```
<service name="Website.WebServices.ddPoplute">
        <endpoint    behaviorConfiguration="Website.WebServices.ddPopluteAspNetAjaxBehavior"
         binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBinding" contract="Website.WebServices.ddPoplute">

        </endpoint>

        <endpoint   behaviorConfiguration="Website.WebServices.ddPopluteAspNetAjaxBehavior"
         binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBindingNotSecure" contract="Website.WebServices.ddPoplute" />
      </service>
```

as mention above in the server that has https everything just fine, but on localhost that doesn't have the ssl I am getting error:

```
Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding WebHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http]
```

If I delete the endpoint with security mode="Transport" the wcf work on the localhost but not on https(in server).

ant idea what to do?

Thnaks

Baaroz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

visual studio doesn't support https and ssl and the error return because the protocol doesn't exist.

for solving the problem you should install iis express and use it in visual studio.

check here for learn how to use iis express

http://joel.net/setting-up-visual-studio-2010-and-iis-express